# What is wrong with this Optional<Class> here?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to iterate list of objects

```
Optional<QueryEntities>  entities =  InputYamlProcessor.process(ymlFilename);

entities.orElseThrow( ()->{
               logger.error("Unable to parse YAL ,Correct YML and retry");
               new NoExtractorDefinedException("Unable to parse YAL ,Correct YML and retry");
           });
```

**Getting error as below :**

The method orElseThrow(Supplier) in the type Optional is not applicable for the arguments (() -> {})

What is wrong am i dong here ?

if QueryEntities class is as belw :

```
public class QueryEntities {

    List<QueryEntity> entitiesList;
   }
```

How to access each QueryEntity and retrieve its fields and print.

Comment: ...I think you just forgot to `return` the `new NoExtractorDefinedException` from your lambda?

Comment: @Naman thow is not working giving error

Comment: You need to use the `return` keyword when you use a block-lambda (`() -> {}`). `return new NoExtractorDefinedException("...");`

Comment: @Naman No, *do not* `throw` the exception. The point is that `orElseThrow` throws it for you. The exception needs to be `return`ed.

Comment: On a more general point, don't log and throw an exception. You will potentially end up with the same single problem showing up in multiple places in the log.

Comment: @Naman yes it is RuntimeException

Comment: @HTNW thank you so much ... can you add the same in answer block , i will accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Optional#orElseThrow
```

takes a

```
Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier
```

(see [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html))

so you must provide it with one:

```
entities.orElseThrow(() -> {
       logger.error("Unable to parse YAL ,Correct YML and retry");
       return new NoExtractorDefinedException("Unable to parse YAL ,Correct YML and retry");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When we pass a lambda expression in this case for  Supplier,

1. If there is only one statement in the lambda expression i.e without {} then dont need to write return statement explictly.

Example:
entities.orElseThrow( ()-> new NoExtractorDefinedException("Unable to parse YAL ,Correct YML and retry"));

2. If lambda expression needs multiple lines i.e {}, then has to return value explictly.

Example:

entities.orElseThrow(() -> {
       logger.error("Unable to parse YAL ,Correct YML and retry");

```
   return new NoExtractorDefinedException("Unable to parse YAL ,Correct YML and retry");
```

});